# How to change string to date type using dask dataframes in python?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, flask, dask

I am parsing JSON data in POST request in my URL and want to extract date and convert that to Date type in Python and all this I am doing in dask. How to convert this?

Previously I have tried using pandas dataframes using:

```
datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').date().__str__()
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right: the list somedates contains string values of dates in the format: "2020-01-23", and you want to convert is to datetime type.

```
import datetime as dt
for i in range(len(somedates)):
    myformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
    somedates[i] = dt.datetime.strptime(somedates[i], myformat)
```